# Bluetoothで接続されたシリアルポートのデバイス名を取得したい

Tags: windows, c#, .net

ユーザーにCOMポートで接続されたデバイスを選択してもらう際、COM15のような表記ではなく、
デバイス名を表示させたい。
下記のコードでシリアルポートに接続されたデバイスの名前をWMIによって取得できますが、
Bluetoothで接続されたデバイスの場合、
「Bluetooth リンク経由の標準シリアル (COMxx)」となり、デバイス名が取得できません。
Bluetoothで接続されたデバイスの名前を取得することは、方法などありましたら、教えて下さい。

```
// using System.Management;
using (var device = new ManagementClass( "Win32_SerialPort" )) {
    foreach( ManagementObject port in device.GetInstances() ) {
        var name = port.GetPropertyValue( "Name" ) as string;
        Console.WriteLine( name );
    }
}
```

開発環境: Windows 7 、C# 6.0 .NET 4.5.1

Answer (score 2):

[32feet.NET](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet)を使うと簡単に取得できそうです。

nugetから32feet.NETで検索して`32feet.NET Personal Area Networking for .NET`の方をインストールします。

ボタンとリストボックスだけ配置したWindows Form アプリケーションで以下の様なコードで取得できるようです…が、そういえば私のマシンはbluetoothオフにしてるので何も取れませんでした（エラーにはなりませんでした）。
(なのでポートとどう紐づけるのかはわかりませんでした。DeviceAddressは取れるみたいですが）

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
    var devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
    foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devices) {
        listBox1.Items.Add(d.DeviceName);
    }
}
```

LicenceはGitHubの方にも書いてありますが、MIT Licenseです。

本家での [この質問(セルフ回答ですが)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908734/get-name-of-bluetooth-device-on-the-devices-and-printers-window) のほか、[イスラエルのMicrosoft blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111222959/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/shair/2009/06/21/working-with-bluetooth-devices-using-c-part-1/)でも紹介されていました。

Answer (score 1):

DiscoverDevicesInRange()は検出可能な状態のデバイス、
DiscoverDevices()は登録済みのデバイスの情報を取得するようです。

登録済みのデバイスの名称のみであれば、先の回答と同じコードにはなりますが
以下で取得できました。

```
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in new BluetoothClient().DiscoverDevices())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(d.DeviceName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

以下のようにすると、COMポートとの紐付けが可能です。
グローバル変数　ArrayList　bluetoothPriniterListに結果が保存されます。

ただし注意事項があります。
スター精密のサーマルプリンタ（mC-Print3）をBluetooth接続した場合の例

```
public void SearchPrinter(object theObj)
        {
            BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices;
            using (BluetoothClient sdp = new BluetoothClient())
                devices = sdp.DiscoverDevices();

            bluetoothPriniterList.Clear();
            foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo deviceInfo in devices)
            {
//                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1})", deviceInfo.DeviceName, deviceInfo.DeviceAddress));

                if(deviceInfo.DeviceName.Contains("mC-Print3"))
                {
                    bluetoothPriniterList.Add(deviceInfo.DeviceName+"|"+ deviceInfo.DeviceAddress.ToString());
                }
            }

            ManagementObjectSearcher serialSearcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
            var query = from ManagementObject s in serialSearcher.Get()
                        select new { Name = s["Name"], DeviceID = s["DeviceID"], PNPDeviceID = s["PNPDeviceID"] }; // DeviceID -- > PNPDeviceID

            foreach (var port in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", port.DeviceID, port.Name);
                var pnpDeviceId = port.PNPDeviceID.ToString();

                if (pnpDeviceId.Contains("BTHENUM"))
                {
                    var bluetoothDeviceAddress = pnpDeviceId.Split('&')[4].Split('_')[0];
                    if (bluetoothDeviceAddress.Length == 12 && bluetoothDeviceAddress != "000000000000")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" - Address: {0}", bluetoothDeviceAddress);
                    }else
                    {
// 注意事項
// スター精密のDeviceIDは、5番目の＆にBluetoothデバイスアドレスがありました。
// DeviceIDの作成方法はベンダーによって異なるようです。
                        try
                        {
                            bluetoothDeviceAddress = pnpDeviceId.Split('&')[5].Split('_')[0];
                            if (bluetoothDeviceAddress.Length == 12 && bluetoothDeviceAddress != "000000000000")
                            {
                                int cc = 0;
                                foreach(string thePrinter in bluetoothPriniterList)
                                {
                                    string myPrinterAddress = thePrinter.Split('|')[1];
                                    if (myPrinterAddress == bluetoothDeviceAddress)
                                        break;

                                    cc++;
                                }

                                if(cc < bluetoothPriniterList.Count)
                                {
                                    bluetoothPriniterList[cc] = bluetoothPriniterList[cc] + "|" + port.Name;
                                    Console.WriteLine(" - myPrinter Info: {0}", bluetoothPriniterList[cc]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```